# Java Swing JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm trying to make a JList to display the contents of an array. The array itself is not an array of strings, however, but an array of Objects.

Is it possible then, to use the same array of objects as the parameter to construct my JList (if the Objects are given a toString method)?

Thanks.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? The idea is to try it first. If it works, great. If not, then you can ask a question stating what happened. You can even post a SSCCE so we can see what you might have done wrong.

Comment: We've decided to go with another method. Thank you.

However, I'm still having problems with updating the JList now.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851217/java-swing-updating-jlist

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is.

> A list uses an object called a cell renderer to display each of its items. The default cell renderer knows how to display strings and icons and it displays Objects by invoking `toString`.

See: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Answer (score 0):

The JList is a MVC based control, like the rest of Swing. You can pass the JList an object array, a string array, or a vector and then supply a ListCellRenderer to render it the objects that you passed in (by default the [DefaultListRenderer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html) is used (which is just a JLabel)).

I don't know what the default behavior if you don't set a ListRender to render the object if you don't pass in strings. It's bad practice. Easy enough to override DefaultListRenender to call Object.ToString() to be safe.

See here more JList info:
http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/tech_topics/jlist_1/jlist.html